# telethon how to get 'alert' message?

Tags: python-3.x, telegram, telethon

[image]

how can i get the 'alert' message ?

my code:

```
@client.on(events.NewMessage(chats=group_to_enter))
async def handler(event):
    buttons = await event.get_buttons()
    for bline in buttons:
        for button in bline:
            print(button.button.text)
            await button.click()
```

but this code cannot get alert message only message displayed in the group

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The result is returned from `Message.click` (or [`MessageButton.click`](https://docs.telethon.dev/en/latest/modules/custom.html#telethon.tl.custom.messagebutton.MessageButton.click)):

```py
result = await button.click()
print(result)
```

Comment: thank you lonami,  i saw the alert text. another question is when the code do `button.click()` , it click the alert button? if not then how can i do it. i searched the internet  and dont find any answer. sorry if it's a dump question

Comment: There is no method to click on the alert button to "close" it. On official clients, it simply closes the modal.